# An integral identity like the Dirac delta function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed. Is the following identity:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{a}^{a+\epsilon}f(x)dx = f(a)$$
true?

This is not homework. I was reading a physics text and the author seems to have used it, but not explicitly. I would like to know if the formula holds, so to conclude I understood it correctly.

Comment: Perhaps they assumed continuity? Look at the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that $\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\delta} \int_x^{x + \delta} f(t) \ \mathrm{d}t = f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281700/showing-that-lim-delta-to-0-frac1-delta-int-xx-delta-ft)

Comment: @Gary it’s not a duplicate of that. That post assumes continuity, in which case it’s easy.

Comment: For the OP, what kind of integrability?

Comment: Take $a=0$ and $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$. This $f$ is Riemann/Lebesgue integrable, yet the statement does not hold. The problem is that $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: This isn't strictly true since integrable functions need not be defined everywhere or can do weird things on measure zero sets. Presumably, the paper meant to assume continuity if it was a physics paper. Physics rarely deals with the full force of measure theory since the laws of physics have regularity built into them which eliminates a lot of pathologies hiding in measure theory.

Comment: Assuming continuity, you can jump straight to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to get the answer.

Comment: Guys, after reviewing the paper, I would say that the author is assuming continuity indeed, in which case the question is a duplicate. I apologize, I was not aware of the previous question, but it is clear now. Thank you all!